# why declare method within square brackets wrapped around name in typescript?

Tags: typescript, nativescript, nativescript-plugin

I've been going through **nativescript** code base to see how to update some of my plugins for {N} 3.0.1, and i see a lot of class methods this way.

```
[srcProperty.setNative](value: any) {
    this._createImageSourceFromSrc(value);
}
```

see the contents of [image-common.ts](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/master/tns-core-modules/ui/image/image-common.ts) and [image.android.ts](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/master/tns-core-modules/ui/image/image.android.ts) to see the full source.

why are the properties of the exported const from **image-common.ts** used in **image.android.ts** a methods, and why are they wrapped in square brackets ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It generates a property with the **computed name** on that class's prototype.

While not very used this perfectly valid javascript/typescript code. It does result in some loss of typing though.

This typescript code:

```js
let propName = 'someMethod';

class A {
  [propName](): number {
    console.log(propName);
    return 5;
  }
}

let a = new A();

let x = a[propName]()
```

Will result in this javascript output.

```js
var propName = 'someMethod';
var A = (function () {
    function A() {
    }
    A.prototype[propName] = function () {
        console.log(propName);
        return 5;
    };
    return A;
}());
var a = new A();
var x = a[propName]();
```

You can see a working example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=let%20propName%20%3D%20'someMethod'%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%5BpropName%5D()%3A%20number%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(propName)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%205%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20a%20%3D%20new%20A()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20x%20%3D%20a%5BpropName%5D()).

Comment: it is highly unusual, first time I see it too, but it makes sense. from a syntax point of view.

Comment: it sure does. Just didn't think about it that way at first